# Getting null pointer exception in Plugin confluence applink rest

Tags: jira, confluence

I was trying to access jira api through confluence. I am getting the following exception,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.jira.AbstractProxyServlet.doProxy(AbstractProxyServlet.java:148)
```

Versions
JIRA v7.6.0
Confluence 6.3.1

And the URL tested 
I tried without specifiying jql still I get same excepotion

```
http://localhost:8090/plugins/servlet/applinks/proxy?appId=b011ce93-79b2-3876-8aa3-a39896872ed6&path=http://localhost:8089/rest/api/latest/search/
```

Comment

Comment: Do you have your Base URLs configured properly in both Applications? Are they both on same machine?

Comment: Yes. Same machine.

Comment: I would recommend adding context path to your applications both JIRA and Confluence. I believe what you are seeing is related to the authentications. When you use two applications on same machines without context path it is pretty common.